# Android Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

How can I remotely start an activity in a different android device using Bluetooth? Is there any way? If so can anyone suggest sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean "take control over another phone" in other terms ? 
Bluetooth would be the mean of physical connection, but i don't know if implementing your own server on Android and thus handling operations like starting apps and so on would be an easy thing... and i'm voluntarily not speaking about security issues ? any experts in there ?

Comment: yes exactly .. even im not worried about security issues . Just i want to control an application .

Comment: @Nemo no business in there but have a look at the paw server app, just found it on the market : or ijetty (google code project). Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, it's pretty easy once you're familiar with bluetooth. You'll have to make server/client connection on both devices with bluetooth (RFCOMM). The client will send a message to the server (by pressing a button or something), server parses the message and executes (starts a certain activity). Take a look at the BluetoothChat example.